# How does a permanent magnet’s field propagate through space?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, field-theory

I kind of know how EM fields travel through space, but what about a permanent magnet’s field? I tend to think of it as a DC version of an EM wave, but then I am left with the question what is the physics behind their means of travel? How do they get from point A to point B? 
Let’s say I remove a magnet from a magnetically shielded box. The space around the box was void of the field until I removed the magnet. Now the entire room and beyond is filled with this field. I know the field becomes weaker with distance, but it does travel well beyond the box. How does a physicist envision this traveling field?

Comment: It *is* an EM field. It's not really even a "DC version" of one if you move it.

Comment: But they don’t travel in straight lines or have a frequency like EM

Comment: If you move a magnet, you get an EM wave, which does have a frequency (or a mix of frequencies), and travels radially outwards.

Comment: Does a "DC version" of something even have a frequency?

Comment: Yes,  DC means 0 freqiency.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a magnetic field to an area where there previously was none, such as in your example by removing shielding, the field strength vs. time at a given point nominally follows a step function. A step function can be represented by an infinite series of sinusoids. So, you can think of the change in field as being carried by a group of EM waves with different frequencies. When all that quiets down later, you're left with a DC or 0 frequency wave. In the real world, the super high frequencies can't be excited for quantum reasons, so the infinite sum isn't perfect and there will be some ringing after the step up in field strength.

Comment: Thanks for devoting time to my question. I knew a moving magnetic field over a conductor produced electricity. I was unaware that a moving magnetic field produced EM waves. So if I wiggle a magnet I am sending out EM waves proportional to the wiggle speed? I know it’s not possible but in theory a fast enough wiggle would produce light?

Comment: Then the moving earth must be producing a lot of E M waves

Comment: Yes, moving a magnet fast enough could make a noticeable EM wave, but moving electrons is a lot easier. A radio antenna is just a big path for electrons to race back and forth to make a radio wave. In order for electrons to oscillate fast enough to make visible light, they typically have to be jumping energy levels within an atom. Now, a magnet you can hold moves a lot slower than an electron in an atom, which is why magnets don't glow when you shake them. They don't make very impressive EM waves.

Comment: Here's an experiment I did with magnetic fields. I was surprised at how far the field reached. Now I am thinking that maybe it is the EM wave generated by the moving magnet that is reaching out rather than the magnetic field itself. Here's the video what are your thoughts?https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pt9547aoRd4

Comment: I'm surprised that worked. What happens if you put your magnets on a drill to spin them?

Comment: Spinning them too fast produces less results. Long sweeping motions produce good results

Comment: The best results come from the twisting hand motions like in the video